# Iphone app archive - No such file or directory

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, archive, restkit

I am almost ready to release my iphone app. I use restkit for consuming my webservice. When I archive, it fails with this error:

**cp: /Users/myusername/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/project-name-/ArchiveIntermediates/project-name/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/include/RestKit: No such file or directory**

I dragged & dropped restkit into the project. It builds and works fine in debug mode. I am guessing it is unable to locate restkit dir while archiving. But I am not sure why. Any thoughts?

Comment: have you checked in summary tab of product, whether framework is present there or not?

Comment: @RIP Yes Summay > Linked Frameworks and Libraries > shows the restkit stuff.. Is that what you meant?

Answer (score 1):

I've had trouble linking with my own framework in the past, but I have a procedure that works.  Even though I don't understand it, it works so I follow it like voodoo, and I don't risk angering the gods by asking too many questions.

Here's what I'd try on your project (again, partly voodoo here):

1. Navigate to the Frameworks folder in the project nav, select the RestKit and delete it with the delete key.  Just delete references.
2. Using Finder, option-drag (copy) the framework from wherever you first got it
   (~/Downloads, or another project or wherever) into your project directory, replacing files if prompted.
3. Back in your project, select the project, then the target, then build phases.
4. Open the link binary section, hit "+", then the "Add Other.." button on the bottom of the dialog
5. Browse to the framework you copied in in step 2.

See if you can clean, build, archive.  Easy enough to try, and no livestock are harmed.  Hope it works for you.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I did as you suggested. Now, while archiving,  xcode complains about a Lexical or Preprocessor issue: "<Restkit/Restkit.h> file not found". It is not able to locate the header!

Comment: Can you see it when you unfold that framework folder?  In the project navigator, under the framework bundle, is there a headers folder that contains the header?

Comment: I just went to the RestKit github page.  Did you try the instructions there?  https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit.  It doesn't match my suggestions.  There's also an extensive visual tutorial here:  https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Installing-RestKit-in-Xcode-4.x.

Comment: Thanks for your effort! Yes I've seen the restkit tuorial & thats the way I had it configured earlier. But it dint work & so tried your approach.