# xCode 4.3 archiving a project with RestKit fails: #import <RestKit/RestKit.h> Not found

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, archive, restkit

When I go to "archive" action in xCode, the action fails at this line:

```
#import <RestKit/RestKit.h>
```

I can run/build a project, and can even do "build for archiving". But when I try to archive the app for the app store, the action fails.

The symptom is that I need to build the project twice for it to run. It feels like this has something to do with build scripts and the copying of the rest kit header action. But I have no experience debugging build scripts.

Has anyone experienced this issue before? **How can I archive a project with the rest kit project included ?**

Thank you!

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8303292/all-restkit-projects-fail-to-build-when-archiving, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8376753/build-for-archiving-work-archive-does-not, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10117629/iphone-app-archive-no-such-file-or-directory.

Comment: I noticed that the rest kit released an "easier to integrate" version. I downloaded and used that. There's a single .a library to include.

Comment: Can you `build` the app against the `Release` configuration ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ended up fixing the build paths as described here to make the app archieve successfully:
[All RestKit projects fail to build when archiving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8303292/all-restkit-projects-fail-to-build-when-archiving)

Answer (score 0):

Did you set all the correct linker flags (not sure if they are needed), for both the release and the debug version.

Archiving a build actually builds the release version.

Comment: Yes, the linker flags were set correctly. I could even do "build for archiving" using the release schema